# Iphone simulator for web development in linux or window

Tags: linux, window, ios-simulator

any suggestion for iphone simulator in linux or window? that have browsing ability to localhost or local network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this 
http://testiphone.com/
not a good one but the browser does it all.No need of simulators;-)

Answer (score 11):

You can install Mac OS X in VirtualBox and then get an Apple developer account and XCode.  Then you can use the iPhone / iPad simulator included.  There are lots of tutorials for installing Mac OS X in VirtualBox, but it still takes about 3-4 hours before you have everything setup.

You can also use Safari on a PC.  They use the same rendering engine (webkit) and act pretty much the same (minus touch related issues).

Comment: Hey Alex, I tried VMWARE, everything works but it doesn't use 3D acceleration. Any idea how to run macOS virtual machine on GPU? (on windows)

Comment: "Apple no longer offers Safari updates for Windows. Safari 5.1.7 for Windows was the last version made for Windows, and it is now outdated."